# Azure DevOps App Center task error: Test chunking failed

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

I have lately been trying to upload our UI-tests to App Center through an Azure DevOps pipeline task and seem to always run into this error. The same error also occurs if I try to run the CLI command locally. Our project is a cross platform Xamarin.Forms app using the Xamarin.UITest test framework.

**The specified error:**

Test chunking failed: Specified method is not supported.

Preparing tests... failed.
Error: Cannot prepare UI Test artifacts using command: C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\xamarin.uitest\3.0.7\tools\test-cloud.exe prepare "D:/a/1/b/Debug/Project.dev.apk" --assembly-dir "D:\a\1\s\ Project.UITest\bin\Debug" --artifacts-dir "D:\a\1\a\AppCenterTest".

Test chunking failed, please try again. If you can't work out how to fix this issue, please contact support.
##[error]Error: D:\a_tasks\AppCenterTest\1.152.3\node_modules.bin\appcenter.cmd failed with return code: 3

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Hi @WhereIsTheExit, could you share a sample here, by the way, please also install the [latest App Center CLI](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-cli/releases) and try it again.

Comment: Any luck with this? Also having this problem